# How can I specify type constraint to have same arguments in two predicates?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I want to create generic event handler function for some custom made events.

Events looks like `Event<T extends Function>` and have `addListener` and `removeListener` method. And then used like this: `type MyEvent = Event<(a1: string, a2: number) => void>`.

My goal is create a function that takes two arguments: such event and predicate with same arguments with event handler. For example for one argument:

```
export function myFunction<A1>(
    event: Event<(a1: A1) => void>,
    predicate: (a1: A1) => boolean): Promise<void> {

}
```

How can I make this function more generic, to be able to handle more than one argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuples in rest parameters to do this:

```
export function myFunction<A extends any[]>(
    event: Event<(...a: A) => void>, // A will be a tuple of parameter types inferred from here
    predicate: (...a: A) => boolean): Promise<void>{
    return Promise.resolve();
}

declare let e: Event<(v: string, n: number) => void>;

myFunction(e, (v, n) => v.length > 0 && n > 0); // v, n typed correctly
myFunction(e, (v) => v.length > 0); // fewer args allowed as usually in TS
myFunction(e, (v, n, z) => v.length > 0); // error here
```